# inserting a tab using python string format

Tags: python, format

I am trying to form a string using format() but can't figure this out.

```
lems = ['scaena', 'persona', 'improbus']
for i in lems:
    print('{}{}{}'.format(i, '\t', 'whatever'))
```

but the tab is not strung as I expect it. Actually, the last item in the list the tab does apply as it prints out:

```
scaena  text
persona text
improbus        text
```

What is going on? thanks.

Comment: It is applying properly in all of them. Look.

Comment: Ok, if I do repr(i) I do see the tabs, however what's up with the extra spaces and why is it that is i write this to a text file my gedit text editor editor does not recognize the tab?

Comment: The extra spaces are how it gets to the next tab stop...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I was having was python unrelated so my question has already the answer in it which I reiterate and mark as the correct answer:

```
for i in lems:
    i = i.strip()
    print('{}{}{}'.format(i, '\t', 'text'))
```

Answer (score 11):

The tab is working properly, you probably are looking for [`.ljust(width)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust)

```py
lems = ['scaena', 'persona', 'improbus']
for i in lems:
    print('{}{}'.format(i.ljust(10), 'whatever'))
```

prints out:

```
scaena    whatever
persona   whatever
improbus  whatever
```

Sometimes it's useful to calculate the max length of your strings so the output is more reliable

```py
lems = ['scaena', 'persona', 'improbus']
max_len = max(len(l) for l in lems)
for i in lems:
    print('{}{}'.format(i.ljust(max_len + 1), 'whatever'))
```

Comment: I don't understand how it is working properly when I can count different spaces between the words, 4 between scaena and whatever, 1 between persona and whatever, the third line has 8 spaces. Also, I NEED the tab because I later write this  to a txt file and and the text editor does not read those as tabs.

Answer (score 5):

I have used that construction:

```
tab = '\t'
file.write(f'''Name{tab}sn{tab}port{tab}sw_sn{tab}sw_port''')
```

Comment: Just using `\t` directly in the f-string works as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the f-string:

```
lems = ['scaena', 'persona', 'improbus']
for i in lems:
    print(f"{i}\t{'whatever'}")
```

You can use the function `repr()` to see that tab is added to the string:

```
from reprlib import repr

lems = ['scaena', 'persona', 'improbus']
for i in lems:
    print(repr(f"{i}\t{'whatever'}"))
```

Output:

```
'scaena\twhatever'
'persona\twhatever'
'improbus\twhatever'
```

Comment: one up for the f"{i}\t{'whatever'}

Answer (score 1):

f-string is another option to achieve the same thing as the answer but in a more compact format. '<10' means to right align with width 10.

```
lems = ['scaena', 'persona', 'improbus']
for i in lems:
    print(f"{i:<10} whatever")
```

Output:

```
scaena     whatever
persona    whatever
improbus   whatever
```