Using \t in loop to seperate values with a tab, Works fine on every output except for the first line
I am doing an assignment for class that requires me to output values separated by a tab. I have no issues with the tab being output on every line except for the first iteration of my loop.
This is my code
input_file = 'StudentInfo.tsv'
student_file = open('StudentInfo.tsv', 'r')
student_info_list = []
student_output = []

for row in student_file:
    student_info_list.append(row.strip().split())

for student in student_info_list:
    name = f'{student[0]}\t{student[1]}'
    average = (int(student[2]) + int(student[3]) + int(student[4])) / 3
    if average >= 90:
        grade = 'A'
    elif 80 <= average < 90:
        grade = 'B'
    elif 70 <= average < 80:
        grade = 'C'
    elif 60 <= average < 70:
        grade = 'D'
    elif average < 60:
        grade = 'F'
    print(f'{name}\t{student[2]}\t{student[3]}\t{student[4]}\t{grade}')

This is the output
Barrett Edan    70  45  59  F

Bradshaw    Reagan  96  97  88  A

Charlton    Caius   73  94  80  B

Mayo    Tyrese  88  61  36  D

Stern   Brenda  90  86  45  C

As you can see every single name and grade is successfully output with a tab, minus the First iterations name. Any idea why this is happening?

What were you expecting?

This similar question may be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952691/inserting-a-tab-using-python-string-format

If you want to align everything, consider '%-10s %s' % (student[0], student[1]) or such so that instead of specifying tabstops you put an actual specific number of characters to align to; that way you aren't dependent for behavior on exactly how your terminal tabstops are configured.

@TimRoberts I already got my answer, but I do see how that it is an important question that I should answer in my post. I will be sure to include what I'm expecting next time. Thanks!

There is nothing wrong here.  A tab character means "advance the cursor to the next tab-stop position".  Tab-stops are generally positioned eight characters apart.
Barrett has seven letters, so the next tab-stop is at position 8, which also just happens to be the actual next character.
So it DID print a tab, it was just very narrow, at one character wide.

I would argue that it depends on the terminal what to do, when a tab character is "printed". In the OPs example, the behavior seems to be to advance to the next multiple of four, but at least one.

I did not know that, very interesting! I appreciate you taking your time to answer my question. Thankyou.

@treuss in ancient times, when the tab character first came about, 8 was the expected tab interval.  It wasn't until later that tab stops became configurable, and 4 is a very common interval today.  But I just tested my copy of IDLE and it's still set to 8 for output even though it's set to 4 for code.
